# Add Header to TListView in c++ (firemonkey)

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder-10.2-tokyo

It is easy to find examples to add a Header item to a TListView in Delphi.  I'm having no luck finding such for c++.  I'm trying to translate [this code](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/adding-headers-to-tlistview-programmatically) from Object Pas to c++ but I can't figure out a translation for the "Purpose.Header".

```
with ListView1.Items.Add do
    begin
      Text := Format('Header %d', [Group]);
      Purpose := TListItemPurpose.Header;
    end;
```

In c++ I have this:

```
ListView1->BeginUpdate();
TListViewItem* item = ListView1->Items->Add();
item->Purpose = ??????????  // this is the line I need syntax for
item->Text = "My Header";
ListView1->EndUpdate();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`TListItemPurpose`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.ListView.Types.TListItemPurpose) is an enum type. FireMonkey is compiled with [scoped enums](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Scoped_Enums_(Delphi)) enabled ([strongly typed enums](https://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-nullptr-strongly-typed-enum-class.html) in C++11 and later).

The Delphi code you showed translates to C++ as follows:

```
TListViewItem *Item = ListView1->Items->Add();
Item->Text = Format(L"Header %d", ARRAYOFCONST(( Group )));
Item->Purpose = TListItemPurpose::Header;
```

Comment: Much obliged Remy!